# How to use the latest C# version in Xamarin Forms projects

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `Xamarin Forms` application. I'd like to use the latest C# version in platform specific projects (i.e. Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android). It looks like I can add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to the .csproj files. However, I'm not sure where to add it exactly. I see a lot of `PropertyGroup` tags in the project files (usually one for each simulator and release type). Do I need to add it to every `PropertyGroup`? I need the latest language version to be available when debugging and in production.

Answer (score 6):

James Montamagno posted a tutorial on his Blog here: https://montemagno.com/use-csharp-8-everywehre/

You just have to change the `<LangVersion />` value of your .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.3.0.947036" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

if you want to change the language of your platform specific code just add:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to your `ProjectName.iOS.csproj` or `ProjectName.Android.csproj`.

Comment: @Agredo This is for PCL though, right? In platform specific projects, I see multiple PropertyGroups.

Comment: But are you supposed to to raise the language like that or will something in my solution break?

Comment: Great answer clear and concise + 1 for mention james hes one my idols as well.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, if you use the latest version of **Target framework**, the version of `C#` will be the latest. Then you will not need to set the version of `C#` manually.

Right click ***the solution of Xamarin Forms***, then click ***Properties***, then can set the ***Target framework*** as follow.

[image]

You will refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults) to know its explains.

[image]

And also can set `C#` version manually in `.csproj` as follow:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here is the C# language version reference.

[image]

Comment: In the iOS and Android csproj files, there are multiple `PropertyGroup` tags. Do I need to add this for every single one of them (i.e. for every simulator and debug/release config)?

Comment: @user246392 Not need. Only add this in Froms `.csproj` is ok.